# How to get last few element from foreach gameobject.transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach

currently i do it manually by checking every loop of array with `if` statement

```
float addGap = gapFix;
foreach (Transform child in topViewPlan.transform)
{
    if (child.name.Substring(5, 2).Equals("45") || child.name.Substring(5, 2).Equals("46") || child.name.Substring(5, 2).Equals("47") || child.name.Substring(5, 2).Equals("48"))
    {
        //rearrange child position
        if (!child.name.Substring(5, 2).Equals("45"))
            child.transform.localPosition += Vector3.right * addGap * 2;
        else
            child.transform.localPosition += Vector3.right * addGap;
    }
}
```

is there any possibilities to get last few element of `topViewPlan.transform` ?
as an example letsay `topViewPlan.transform` consist of 10 element, and I want last 4 element (which is element 7,8,9 and 10) so maybe I could write :-

```
foreach (Transform child in topViewPlan.transform.getLast(4)){} //this is just example
```

so i could get last 4 element of the `topViewPlan.transform`

Answer (score 2):

You can use *GetComponentsInChildren< Transform >()* which will give you and array with child and the object itself.

for exemple :

```
var childs = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
int offset = 5; // want the five last elements
for(int i=childs.Length - offset; i<childs.Length; ++i)
{
    // Do something with childs[i]
}
```

But I would assume that this code is inefficient and unstable, I can't assure that the array returned by *GetComponentsInChildren* is sorted in the right way (parent at 0 and childrens afterwards). A more sure and easy way would be that every child of your GameObject have a particular component, let's say :

```
class ChildrenIdentificator : MonoBehavior
{
    public int id = 0;
}
```

You would set the id in every child so it have the behavior you want and then you can do :

```
var childs = GetComponentsInChildren<ChildrenIdentificator>();
for(int i=0 ; i<childs.Length ; ++i)
{
    if(childs[i].id == // I let you figure out the rest
}
```

This way you have a better control and you can see directly what you are doing. You also avoid doing string comparison.
In any case I strongly recommand to not use *GetComponentsInChildren* at each frame, to solve that you can store the childs array in the Start() function before using it afterward.

Comment: If you need to grab deactivated objects, add the true parameter to GetComponentsInChildren.

Comment: I prefer your first method but the problem is `var childs = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();` return child `recursively` while `foreach (Transform child in topViewPlan.transform)` only return first depth of child.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
transform.childCount
```

to get number of childs then to get a child do this :

for example this will return child number 5 :

```
transform.GetChild(5);
```

the code you need :

```
int numberOfChildNeeded = 5;
for (int i = transform.childCount - 1; i > transform.childCount - numberOfChildNeeded ; i--)
{
    //do something
    transform.GetChild(i)
}
```